# remove rows from cell based on multiple conditions

Tags: matlab

I have a cell with dimensions of 50 x 2. A subset of the table is shown below.

```
code   num
AAA    5
AAA    6
BBB    12
AAA    4
CCC    5
```

I want to find any rows where the code is equal to AAA and the num is not equal to 4. Then remove these rows to leave me with,

```
code   num
AAA    4
BBB    12
CCC    5
```

I have tried the following,

indx_remove = rf_cell(:, 1) == 'AAA' && rf_cell(:, 2) ~= '4';

This line gives me undefined function eq for input arguments of type cell.

Comment: Your result isn't right, is it? You should be left with `AAA 5 AAA 6 BBB 12 CCC 5`? You want to remove the rows where `code = AAA and num != 4`?

Comment: I also want the AAA 4 left in. I want any rows where the code is equal to AAA and the num not equal to 4 to be removed. Believe what I have posted is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
A(strcmp(A(:,1),'AAA') &([A{:,2}]'~=4),:) = []
```

Comment: This seems to be a very neat solution but I tried this and I got zero results. `ans = {}(0x2)`

Comment: Sorry, I made a sloppy mistake, it should be fixed now!

Comment: Yep. That worked. +1 but how can the `4` be included when you actually exclude it in `([A{:,2}]'~=4),:)`?

Comment: Ah, you are actually doing it the other way around. You remove all values equal to `AAA` **and** not equal to `4`, i.e. `=='AAA' & ~=4`. Not bad...

Comment: `strcmp(A(:,1),'AAA') &([A{:,2}]'~=4)` gives you a logical column vector with a `1` in all the rows where the first entry of the corresponding row in `A` is `'AAA'`, and the second entry of the corresponding row in `A` is different `4`. That is it finds the rows to be removed. Edit: Looks like I got ninjaed,

Answer (score 1):

I believe I am doing this the hard way, but I hope it is not too stupid.

code   num
    AAA    5
    AAA    6
    BBB    12
    AAA    4
    CCC    5

%generate code vector and num vector

`code = ['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA','CCC']`

code = AAAAAABBBAAACCC

`num = [5;6;12;4;5]`

`k = strfind(code, 'AAA')` %find your index

k = 1     2     3     4    10 %because the vector code is just a concatenation of your sub-strings, you will need to sort the index out

%here, you can do something smart, your choice, I use modulo, since your char length is 3 characters, the modulo 3 should return 1 for it to be the starting index.

`b = mod(k,3)`

b = 1     2     0     1     1

`index  = k(find(b==1))`  % 1, 4, 10 returned

`column1 = floor(index/3+1)` %output 1 2 4, which is the rows with AAA

`check = num(floor(column1/3+1))` % just a checking stage, output 5 6 4 of num.

now you have the index of your column 1 for the strings that has AAA for value. Now you find for you column 2 the value 4s

`column2 = find(num==4)` % output 4

you can write a if statement to remove index [number 4] if both column1 and column2 contains the same number and remove that value (which refers to the index)

Happy coding!

Comment: Please read this post on code formatting for your future answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks - You give good answers, but I find that your code formatting is distracting (actually non-existent).

Answer (score 1):

```
ind = cellfun(@(x,y) strcmp(x,'AAA') & y~=4, {A{:,1}}, {A{:,2}}) '
A(find(ind==0),:)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = BBB
  [2,1] = AAA
  [3,1] = CCC
  [1,2] =  12
  [2,2] =  4
  [3,2] =  5
}
```

---

### Details

```
% // Create the values

A = {'AAA',    5;
'AAA'   , 6;
'BBB'   , 12;
'AAA'   , 4;
'CCC'   , 5};

%// Create a cell array of the values

{A{:,1}}, {A{:,2}}

ans =
{
  [1,1] = AAA
  [1,2] = AAA
  [1,3] = BBB
  [1,4] = AAA
  [1,5] = CCC
}
ans =
{
  [1,1] =  5
  [1,2] =  6
  [1,3] =  12
  [1,4] =  4
  [1,5] =  5
}

%// Create an anonymous function that will be applied to each element of our cell.
%// It will take the elements of the first cell (represented by `x` in the anonymous function)
%// and compare it to `AAA` and the elements of the second cell (`y`) and compare it to `4`.
%// The result is an array with the logical result of the conditions.

ind = cellfun(@(x,y) strcmp(x,'AAA') & y~=4, {A{1:size(A,1),1}}, {A{1:size(A,1),2}}) '

ind =

1
1
0
0
0

%// Then find the rows where these were zero as we wanted to exclude those values

A(find(ind==0),:)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = BBB
  [2,1] = AAA
  [3,1] = CCC
  [1,2] =  12
  [2,2] =  4
  [3,2] =  5
}
```